# PHP Variable Function Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

I need to use variable function names for a project I'm working on but have run into a bit of strange issue. The function name ends up as a string element in an array.

This works:

```
$func = $request[2];
$pages->$func();
```

This doesn't:

```
$pages->$request[2]();
```

And I can't figure out why. It throws an array to string conversion error, as if it's ignoring that I have supplied a key to a specific element. Is this just how it works or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for **php 5**, you can use curly-braced syntax:

```
$pages->{$request[2]}();
```

Simple enough example to reproduce:

```
<?php

$request = [
    2 => 'test'
];

class Pages
{
    function test()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

$pages = new Pages();

echo $pages->{$request[2]}();
```

Alternatively (as you noted in the question):

```
$methodName = $request[2];
$pages->$methodName();
```

Quote from [**php.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) for **php 7** case:

> Indirect access to variables, properties, and methods will now be
>   evaluated strictly in left-to-right order, as opposed to the previous
>   mix of special cases.

Also there is a table for **php 5** and **php 7** differences for this matter just below quote in the docs I've supplied here.

*Which things you should consider:*

- Check value of the `$request[2]` (*is it really a **string**?*).
- Check your version of php (*is it **php 5+** or **php 7+**?*).
- Check manual on [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) for your release.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for documentation covering this and couldn't find it. I'll accept your answer as soon as the timer lets me.

Comment: Beat me too it, +1  Could also ( maybe ? ) use ReflectionFunction class and invoke, but it's a bit overkill for this.   http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yeah, there is also `call_user_func()`. Still, I believe, that this question is about syntax more, than about solution to a problem.